# count the fields without empty line using awk command

Tags: awk

```
safwanpaloli@hello:~/linx$ cat 1.txt 

Name    age address email
safwan  26  india   safwanp@gmail.com
rashi   24  India   rashi@gmail.com
shanif  25  India   shanif@gmail.com
pradeep 25  India   pradeep@gmil.com
safwanpaloli@hello:~/linx$
```

Display the line number with all file content

> awk '{print NR,$0}'

output is

```
1 
2 Name  age address     email
3 safwan    26  india   safwanp@gmail.com
4 rashi     24  India   rashi@gmail.com
5 shanif    25  India   shanif@gmail.com
6 pradeep   25  India   pradeep@gmil.com
```

expected result is

```
1 Name  age address     email
2 safwan    26  india   safwanp@gmail.com
3 rashi     24  India   rashi@gmail.com
4 shanif    25  India   shanif@gmail.com
5 pradeep   25  India   pradeep@gmil.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This prints non empty lines, with their count. To be counted, the line must contain at least one non whitespace character.

```
awk '$1!="" {print ++c,$0}'
```

This is similar, but only *completely* empty lines are skipped. Eg. a line containing nothing but a single space would still get counted.

```
awk '/./ {print ++c,$0}'
```

You can also remove empty lines with one of these greps:

```
grep '[^[:space:]]'

grep .
```

Answer (score 2):

You could examine if `NF` has a value greater than 0 and use a counter variable:

```
$ awk 'NF{print ++c,$0}' file
```

Output:

```
1 Name    age address email
2 safwan  26  india   safwanp@gmail.com
...
```

If the first line is truly empty (ie. no space in there) you could use `nl file`. It will  print the empty line but not number it.

Above `nl` functionality with awk (empty lines output but not numbered):

```
$ awk '{print (NF?++c:""),$0}' file
```

Output:

```
1 Name    age address email
2 safwan  26  india   safwanp@gmail.com
3 rashi   24  India   rashi@gmail.com
...
```